# good precision for sync time with NTP over JavaScript

Tags: javascript, synchronization, ntp

I want to synchronize the time with NTP over JavaScript.
The client can be a normal pc or a smartphone or tablet. The connection could be WLAN or 3G, etc.

I already found this questions and sites

- [how to get ntp time from through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818411/how-to-get-ntp-time-from-through-javascript)
- [JavaScript NTP time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522191/javascript-ntp-time)
- http://jehiah.cz/a/ntp-for-javascript
- [Synchronize time in javascript with a good precision (>0.5s) (NTP-like)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478179/synchronize-time-in-javascript-with-a-good-precision-0-5s-ntp-like)

first and second links using the a timestamp from this server: `http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json`
But the date object has only second precision. I want a better precision, if possible ~ 10 ms. (I know the precision depends on the connection and round trip time)
**Edit:** *10 ms is almost impossible. I want the most precision offset.*

The third link shows a JavaScript library, but it does not use a direct connection to a ntp server. The solution of the fourth link is most near to that what I want. But its for synchronizing two clients through a 'own' server. Is there a way to synchronize it directly to a ntp pool like `pool.ntp.org` ?

Comment: `Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=68ms TTL=44

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 68ms, Maximum = 68ms, Average = 68ms`
 How are you going to get sub 10ms with that?

Comment: You might be interested in [Sync JS time between multiple devices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10585910/1048572), which offers many solutions.

Comment: @Bergi This is abou synchronization, but not with NTP

Comment: @starbolin The error ist worst case is only half of the round trip time. Okay 10ms isn't possible. I want only the most precision value.

Comment: No, the uncertainty, without clock disciplining, is the difference between the best case one way time and the worst case one-way time. Which may, at times, be more than the average round trip time. Worst case time is not garanteed in a best-effort network ( TCP/IP ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NTP client servos the computer's own internal clock for resolution. The client must estimate UDP round trip times and change the inernal clock *rate* ,slowly, to minimize the average error.

Comment: Okay, I found that JavaScript can not handle UDP requests, so there is no directly solution for it?!

Comment: Nope. Not using NTP, at least. And definitely not in JavaScript, as that can't change the system clock.

Comment: @duskwuff I don't want to change the system time, I will work with the NTP offset.

Comment: Rfc5905 - NTP is a server-to-server synchronization protocol not a time service.

Comment: server-server you sure? because with android you can use NTP. An androi device act as a server? I don't understand why it should be a server.